# if statement causing white screen

Tags: php, if-statement

i have the if statement below i am trying to make sure that the variable client2 is not empty before doing the update, as the update has to be performed to that client, but ever time i uncomment the if statement it gives a white screen

```
if(!empty($client2)
    {
        mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Could not update ");
        header('Location: preview.php?=client=$client');
    }
```

what i would like is for it not to produce a white screen i suspect it is minor error i have overlooked

the problem also existed before i added

```
    header('Location: preview.php?=client=$client');
```

this was added as it the final step it needs to do after doing the update but i will have to add a check in to display the error if it fails the update before doing the header but for now i am focusing on getting it to do the update regardless of mysql errors

Comment: You have missed closing bracket in empty client checking

Comment: You should note that variable inserts don't happen inside of single quote strings. It should be `header("Location: preview.php?client=$client");` or concatenate with `header('Location: preview.php?client='.$client);`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You do miss a closing bracket in your if. Empty is a function and needs to be opened and closed with brackets (). As is the IF function. In other words, you don't close your IF function so PHP assumes that everything after emtpy() is still part of the IF closure.

Also, try never working (in development env ofc) without display_error being abled.

Besides that, your header function has a '=' after the question mark. Its not needed and will eventually fail.

Comment: `In other words, you don't close your IF function so PHP assumes that everything after emtpy() is still part of the IF closure.` First up, `if` is not a function. Secondly, if you don't have that bracket that's a syntax error and php doesn't even bother to go through the code to `assume` the outcome of that `if`

Comment: It's not a `constructor` either :). Its a language construct present in almost all languages. If doesn't behave like functions either. Its a conditional statement. `The if construct is one of the most important features of many languages, PHP included. It allows for conditional execution of code fragments. PHP features an if structure that is similar to that of C: `

Comment: And when there is a syntax error then PHP doesn't try to execute the code at all, there are no if conditions evaluated. The parser terminates and returns on the first occurrence of a syntax error.

Comment: @Chilion If anything, an `if` statement _handles_ a result.

Comment: Ok no point in wasting further time here :)

Answer (score 4):

Your header is wrong you should do it like this:

```
header("Location: preview.php?client=$client");
```

You've also forgot a `)` here:

```
if(!empty($client2))
```

Comment: [See my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550100/if-statement-causing-white-screen#comment39895400_25550100) about the header problem too... consider revising